# Divide an image into random parts - like a puzzle

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, numpy, image-processing

**Input:** image
**Output:** Random division to N parts of the image.
The output can be actual images, or Chain Code for borders, or any other way which will help to  distinguish the different parts and use them later.

For example (9 parts):
input:
[image]

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question, but if I had to do it, I would probably start by doing splines. I'd take N points

```
(w/3 * (1+random()),0)
(w/3 * (1+random()),h/N)
(w/3 * (1+random()),2*h/N)
...
(w/3 * (1+random()),h)
```

where N is something like 10, and random() returns a number between say -0.3 and 0.3, and pass a spline through these. I repeat this at 2*w/3 and get another curve. Then I do the same horizontally.

This means that the pieces will look like curved rectangles. But you can refine the horizontal lines to maybe not be in one straight shot, but instead have bits between the left border and the first vertical spline, then another curve between the first and second vertical spline.

Answer (score 0):

```
import image_slicer
import random
randomNum=random.randint(2,14)
imSlic=image_slicer.slice("user/Desktop/1.jpg", randomNum)
```

**these code help you slice any image into random part between 2 and 14**
but first you should install these two modules